# How does one extend the User model on cloudfroundry UAA

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

We are currently evaluating using Cloud Foundry UAA as an OAuth 2.0 authorization server and I have not been able to find any documentation around how to extend the user model.

I see that UAA leverages SCIM, which is itself extensible, but how does one specify how to retrieve/save the custom attributes from a persistent store?
(e.g. is there, for example, a user details service or provider one can implement and inject?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was raised, and closed.  I'd be interested in the solution here as well.
 [Pivotal Issue Tracker link](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/997278/stories/141235205)

According to the git comments there are no plans to make UAA a user store, and therefore no plans to allow the user model to be extended.
[Github Issue #554 link](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues/554)